# json deserialize of ListBuffer[(String,String)] in play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

i am developing app using play framework in scala i want response in json but how to do that compile time error is coming

```
 No Json deserializer found for type List[(String, String)]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

List buffer is

```
ListBuffer((This,a choke), (a Cv,15.6 gal))
```

i also did this

```
Json.toJson(list))
```

but still getting error.

any one give me some idea to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What json representation of `(String, String)` do you expect it to be?
If it is something like this:

```
yourListName : {
  "1" : "2",
  "3" : "4"
}
```

then you could just use `Json.toJson(list.toMap)`. Otherwise, you must define a `Writes` for a `(String, String)` like this:

```
implicit val writer = new Writes[(String, String)] {
    def writes(c: (String, String)): JsValue = {
      Json.obj("something" -> c._1 + ", " + c._2)
      //or like this:
      //Json.obj(c._1 -> c._2)
    }
  }
```

Be sure to have this writer in scope

Comment: can you please help me for this also `No Json deserializer found for type Map[String,Any]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`



`Map(sentence2 -> Map("UOM " -> List(Map(This -> a choke Cv equal to 15.6 gal/min psi½), Map(This -> 15.6 gal/min psi½), Map(This -> 120 bara,), Map(This -> 110 gal/min psi½), Map(This -> 120 bara.), Map(a choke Cv -> a choke Cv equal to 15.6 gal/min psi½), Map(a choke Cv -> 15.6 gal/min psi½),`

for that kind of data

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in this thread [[2.1] Json.format macros and Tuple2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/kn-gRW8KSwQ) play-json 2.1 doesn't support tuples yet mainly because json doesn't support tuples. If you want your tuples to be writtern as an array you might use implicit format for tuples:

```
implicit def tuple2Writes[A, B](implicit aWrites: Writes[A], bWrites: Writes[B]): Writes[Tuple2[A, B]] = new Writes[Tuple2[A, B]] {
  def writes(tuple: Tuple2[A, B]) = JsArray(Seq(aWrites.writes(tuple._1), bWrites.writes(tuple._2)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a line, simply declare this implicit:

```
implicit def tuple2[A : Writes, B : Writes] = Writes[(A, B)] ( t =>  Json.obj("something1" -> t._1, "something1" -> t._2) )
```